# How to reach only an application in QEMU emulation without X?

Tags: openbsd, qemu

I run an OpenBSD guest on an OpenBSD host (Desktop) with QEMU. Because I want to run a webbrowser in a separated environment. I can reach the QEMU machine via ssh -X so I can see the webbrowser. But that's not really safe (because AFAIK X wasn't designed by security in mind).

**Q:** How can I reach the webbrowser (xxxterm) from the host OpenBSD machine safely and with good performance?

ps.: [question is based on this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91686/18526)

Comment: It might be easier and to much less secure to run the browser on the same computer under a different user and/or in `jail`.

Answer (score 1):

If you start qemu from your desktop environment, you can use one of its GUIs directly to access the VM.

Alternatively, you can use vnc (or maybe spice) as recommended in the answer you linked.

Both options requires, that you have a running X environment inside your VM.